# Communication with paired BLE device from Windows 8

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I understand there is no API for Windows 8 BLE or Bluetooth 4, however Windows 8 allows you to see and pair with BLE devices through the Windows Bluetooth Manager.

My question is is there any way to communicate (through a COM or Serial Port for example) with a paired BLE device on Windows 8?

Preferably in C++ or C# as I intend to create a DLL which I can import in Unity3D.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the need to pair with the device in windows bluetooth manager manually.

What I've done to solve my problem was to buy the BlueGiga BLED112 dongle, which has a C library that allows you to communicate with the device through a COM port. [Here is the link to BLED112](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/bled112-bluetooth-smart-dongle/). And you also have [this lib](https://github.com/jrowberg/bglib/tree/master/MSVCSharp), which is written in C# and allows you to do what you want in a more kind way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Paradela, Thanks for this info on BlueGiga device. I currently have one and I am trying to connect it to a bluetooth calliper where I can get some data from the calliper in C#. The problem I currently have is how to establish connection between the dongle and the calliper. The C# library do not have documentation, so I am struglling to understand how to use it.

Comment: Hello @Kunbi. I haven't worked in this for a while. But if I can recall, the C# lib had a few examples that of how to search for BLE devices and how to connect to them. Have you tried to run those examples?

Comment: Hi Paradela,Thanks so much for replying me. I tried the c# lib examples, there are three main examples and the challenge I have with them is they require a UUID for whatever instrument one is using, meanwhile I can't find the UUID for a caliper and also using the discovery module of it, It doesn't give me a readable information about the caliper. I sent a message to the owner of the library but no response yet.

Comment: @Kunbi to discover a UUID I use an application from Google Play Store on my Android phone. If you search for "BLE Scanner" you should find some good options. I think theres a few for iOS as well. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Paradela. I finally got it working. The tool I am using requires a bespoke application from its maker to work despite it having a bluetooth.